# Split View Controller without nib/xib files

Tags: uisplitviewcontroller, ipad, uisplitview

I have a class of `NSObject` through which i'm trying to add a `SplitViewController`. I have two files named as "Master" and "Detail" but without xib's. I want to create a split view controller using these files. I have tried adding them as the normal split view code but i only get a blank screen. I am not able to see the detail view and also on rotating the device i cannot see the master-detail pane in landscape mode.

All kind of help is welcome. Thanks in advance.